# How do I prevent power query from refreshing other queries?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I created 4 queries from different data sources (ex., East, West, Central, South) that then I want to merge into a master (ex., "Corporate") report. How can I prevent power query in excel from rerunning the first 4 queries every time I run the Corporate report? I want to be able to run the master report based on the current data already extracted.

Comment: You cant.  If the source of a query is another query, its going to run those source queries when you refresh it.  And why would you want it differently? If you have static data, load that to a hard coded table and use it that way

Comment: Thank you. This helps me better organize my workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. The are two tricks to it.

Trick 1 is to have your North/South/East/West queries as usual, and load to a worksheet, *and* also have NorthCached/SouthCached/EastCached/WestCached queries that read output tables as if they were inputs.

But when I tried having a query or parameter named `FullCalculations` that was a logical/boolean `true` or `false`, and used that in my queries, like...

```
  ...
  EastReport = if FullCalculations then
    East
  else
    EastCached,
  ...
```

... imagine my surprise to find that instead of running one or the other, it runs **both**!

So the second trick is to have a query like

## fPossiblyCached

```
(QueryName as text) => Record.Field(
  #shared,
  QueryName & (
    if FullCalculations then
      ""
    else
      "Cached'
  )
)
```

`#shared` is the record of all your queries and even built-in functions (like `Record.Field`) that are available in the current context. By getting the query you want in this way it doesn't load both.

... but now you've just made your workbook a lot more complicated. It might not be worth it!